# I have a Django web app that is connected to S3 for storage of images, dont know how to combine python code

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django application that gets deployed to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. The main concept of the app is that the user uploads images to the website, the image gets stored in a S3 bucket. From here my plan is to take the image from the S3 bucket make a call to Microsoft API for Facial Recognition and then return the result to the user. But I have no idea how to combine the code for the API call with the Django app?

I have the code, I just dont know where to put it so it is run when a user uploads an image.

Answer (score 0):

An AWS Lambda function is an easy way to trigger the jobs without touching your existing Django code. Just make a functiom in Lambda that processes the image after adding to bucket and returns the result to another Django HTTP callback URL.

Another options include Django signals (synchronous tasks) and Celery tasks (asynchronous tasks), but those require tying your recognition into your Django application. This can be preferable or unwanted, but you have to figure which it is yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant how to store & retrieve images/media files from s3 you can use [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages), it is a collection of custom storage backends for Django, supporting like amazon s3 to azure storages, try it